# Store the output of shell command in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to install zfs through shell script while installation I am getting some error so, to automate it fully, I want to get the version to be installed from error itself. For all other commands I am getting the error in one variable but for one command its not coming at all. I tried every solution possible.

I need output of this command

```
sploutput=$(sudo dkms install -m spl -v $version)

echo $sploutput

echo $sploutput # This is giving nothing.
```

I tried wrapping it around string also like `"sploutput=$(sudo dkms install -m spl -v $version)"`

```
echo "{sploutput}"
```

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sploutput=$(sudo dkms install -m spl -v $version)
echo $sploutput
```

it *might* be because the `dkms install` outputs on `STDERR` and not on `STDOUT`, and with the command you're using, you're only getting `STDOUT` output in the variable. To take both, you can try:

```
sploutput=$(sudo dkms install -m spl -v $version 2>&1)
```

to redirect `STDERR` into `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

As per ZMO's answer: try running  `sudo dkms install -m spl -v $version`

See, what is it returning? : STDERR or STDOUT.

In case, if it fails, it won't show up anything in sploutput. 
It write only STDOUT to the variable.

Use **2>&1(to write Standard error to standard output)**. 
You can refer [IO redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_02.html#sect_05_02_01)

You can use following:

```
sploutput=$(sudo dkms install -m spl -v $version 2>&1)
echo $sploutput
```